How does `performance.now()` work in TMS WEB Core?
I'm trying to use the performance.now() method, but using Delphi in TMS WEB Core.
In JavaScript I can do this:
const t0 = window.performance.now();

for (let i = 0; i < 100000; i++) {
  // some code
}

const t1 = window.performance.now();
console.log(`For Loop took ${t1 - t0} milliseconds.`);

I can see that in the Delphi IDE code completion, there is a window.performance which is of type TJSPerformance:

But I'm not sure how to use it and I can't find any documentation on it. If I ctrl+left-click into TJSPerformance, it's defined in the Web unit, but it's empty:
TJSPerformance = class(TJSObject)
end;

But I've seen many things that appear empty when I ctrl+left-click, but then they still work and actually have things in it somewhere.
I'm not able to do window.Performance.now() in Delphi as that results in an error that says:

[Error] uIndex.pas(197): identifier not found "now"

I basically want to use this to calculate the execution time of Delphi code in TMS WEB Core.
So how does window.Performance and window.performance.now() work in Delphi?

Use SysUtils.Now(). Works for me with TMS Web Core.

And to write number of milliseconds, use IntToStr(TTimeSpan.Subtract(t1,t0).Milliseconds)
